# how to ensure existence and uniqueness of the maximizer of a function with not compact domain

Tags: convex-optimization

Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $A\subset \mathbb{R}^d$.
It looks like I can ensure existence and uniqueness of a maximizer of $f$ if I let $f$ be strictly concave and upper semicontinuous with bounded super-level sets. I wonder why this is true and moreover what conditions should I place on $A$. I would like to avoid $A$ being bounded. I wonder if I can let $A$ be an open or closed rectangle.

Comment: It is not true, let $A=(0,1)$ and $f(x) = x$, then $f$ has no maximiser.

Comment: Thanks. What if $A$ is closed e.g. $A=[3,+\infty)$? Is the statement true if I let $A$ be a closed rectangle? Can I let $A$ be a closed convex set?

Comment: No, try $f(x) = 1-e^{-x}$ on $x \ge 0$. You need to try some simple examples  yourself.

Comment: Does the logarithm $\log : \left[ 3, +\infty \right) \to \mathbb{R}$ which is strictly concave on a closed connected set have a maximizer? Edit: Oh, my example was unbounded, but copper.hat's works.

Comment: Neither $f(x)=1-e^{-x}$ has a maximizer on $[0,+\infty)$ nor the $\log$ function on $[3,+\infty)$ but they do not have bounded superlevel sets.

Comment: You are right. Wikipedia states: _By Weierstrass's theorem, the boundness of some non-empty sublevel set and the lower-semicontinuity of the function implies that a function attains its minimum._

Comment: Thank you. I believe that is referred to functions defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}^d$. But if a function is defined only on a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^d$, what conditions should I place on $A$?

Comment: It should be enough that $A$ is closed, I believe. If you can pick just one nonempty superlevel set which is bounded, then it is clear that the maximum cannot occur outside the closure (which will be compact and inside $A$) of that set?

Comment: ($A$ would automatically be a convex set, otherwise it will not make sense to assume $f$ is strictly concave.)

Comment: Thank you. To my understanding, we need to exploit that the superlevel set is also convex because $f$ is concave (to ensure uniqueness of the maximizer by strict concavity) and that the superlevel set is closed because $f$ is upper semicontinuous. So probably, as you suggest, we only need to let $A$ be closed and convex.

Comment: Sorry, I misread, I missed the super-level sets part. If a super level set is non empty and bounded then you are essentially dealing with the compact case.